# Are Aliases to be used outside the Select in which they are declared?

Tags: sqlite, subquery, alias

everyone. I have a table with one of the fields (seq) declared as varchar(14), containing a string of numbers (five 2digits numbers separated by whitespaces). I'd like to get, for each row, the 5 possible combination of 4 of those numbers ***Union All*** into a single column. My first attempt leads to the following query, which 'should' work (although i admit it is 'a bit' awful!) :

```
SELECT id,ordered_seq FROM(
    SELECT id,
           seq,
           MIN(SUBSTR(seq,1,2),SUBSTR(seq,4,2),SUBSTR(seq,7,2),SUBSTR(seq,10,2),SUBSTR(seq,13,2)) AS A1,
           MAX(SUBSTR(seq,1,2),SUBSTR(seq,4,2),SUBSTR(seq,7,2),SUBSTR(seq,10,2),SUBSTR(seq,13,2)) AS E1,
           trim(replace(replace(replace(replace(seq,A1,''),'  ',' '),E1,''),'  ','')) AS T1,

           MIN(SUBSTR(T1,1,2),SUBSTR(T1,4,2),SUBSTR(T1,7,2)) AS B1,
           MAX(SUBSTR(T1,1,2),SUBSTR(T1,4,2),SUBSTR(T1,7,2)) AS D1,
           replace(replace(replace(T1,B1,''),D1,''),'  ','') AS C1,
           A1||' '||B1||' '||C1||' '||D1||' '||E1 AS ordered_seq
    FROM source_table
)
WHERE(seq<>'00 00 00 00 00')
```

This one should return the original column where each row is sorted in ascending order, while providing 'indexes' for the final part of the job: selecting all the possible combinations of 4 numbers per row, as i said before.
Problem is, i get a 'no such column' error on first attempt to use an alias inside the select where it has been declared  (i.e. select col1 as c1, count(c1) raises 'no such column : C1' error). Is this a normal behaviour?

My usual luck.

Updated query -----------------------------

```
SELECT id, fir||' '||sec||' '||thi||' '||fou||' '||fif AS ordered_list 
FROM (
   SELECT id,
          Date,
          seq,
          MIN(SUBSTR(seq,1,2),SUBSTR(seq,4,2),SUBSTR(seq,7,2),SUBSTR(seq,10,2),SUBSTR(seq,13,2)) AS fir,
          MIN( SUBSTR(trim(replace(replace(replace(replace(seq,MIN(SUBSTR(seq,1,2),SUBSTR(seq,4,2),SUBSTR(seq,7,2),SUBSTR(seq,10,2),SUBSTR(seq,13,2)),''),'  ',' '),MAX(SUBSTR(seq,1,2),SUBSTR(seq,4,2),SUBSTR(seq,7,2),SUBSTR(seq,10,2),SUBSTR(seq,13,2)),''),'  ',' ')),1,2), SUBSTR(trim(replace(replace(replace(replace(seq,MIN(SUBSTR(seq,1,2),SUBSTR(seq,4,2),SUBSTR(seq,7,2),SUBSTR(seq,10,2),SUBSTR(seq,13,2)),''),'  ',' '),MAX(SUBSTR(seq,1,2),SUBSTR(seq,4,2),SUBSTR(seq,7,2),SUBSTR(seq,10,2),SUBSTR(seq,13,2)),''),'  ',' ')),4,2), SUBSTR(trim(replace(replace(replace(replace(seq,MIN(SUBSTR(seq,1,2),SUBSTR(seq,4,2),SUBSTR(seq,7,2),SUBSTR(seq,10,2),SUBSTR(seq,13,2)),''),'  ',' '),MAX(SUBSTR(seq,1,2),SUBSTR(seq,4,2),SUBSTR(seq,7,2),SUBSTR(seq,10,2),SUBSTR(seq,13,2)),''),'  ',' ')),7,2) ) AS sec,
          trim( replace(replace(trim(replace(replace(replace(replace(seq,MIN(SUBSTR(seq,1,2),SUBSTR(seq,4,2),SUBSTR(seq,7,2),SUBSTR(seq,10,2),SUBSTR(seq,13,2)),''),'  ',' '),MAX(SUBSTR(seq,1,2),SUBSTR(seq,4,2),SUBSTR(seq,7,2),SUBSTR(seq,10,2),SUBSTR(seq,13,2)),''),'  ',' ')),MIN( SUBSTR(trim(replace(replace(replace(replace(seq,MIN(SUBSTR(seq,1,2),SUBSTR(seq,4,2),SUBSTR(seq,7,2),SUBSTR(seq,10,2),SUBSTR(seq,13,2)),''),'  ',' '),MAX(SUBSTR(seq,1,2),SUBSTR(seq,4,2),SUBSTR(seq,7,2),SUBSTR(seq,10,2),SUBSTR(seq,13,2)),''),'  ',' ')),1,2), SUBSTR(trim(replace(replace(replace(replace(seq,MIN(SUBSTR(seq,1,2),SUBSTR(seq,4,2),SUBSTR(seq,7,2),SUBSTR(seq,10,2),SUBSTR(seq,13,2)),''),'  ',' '),MAX(SUBSTR(seq,1,2),SUBSTR(seq,4,2),SUBSTR(seq,7,2),SUBSTR(seq,10,2),SUBSTR(seq,13,2)),''),'  ',' ')),4,2), SUBSTR(trim(replace(replace(replace(replace(seq,MIN(SUBSTR(seq,1,2),SUBSTR(seq,4,2),SUBSTR(seq,7,2),SUBSTR(seq,10,2),SUBSTR(seq,13,2)),''),'  ',' '),MAX(SUBSTR(seq,1,2),SUBSTR(seq,4,2),SUBSTR(seq,7,2),SUBSTR(seq,10,2),SUBSTR(seq,13,2)),''),'  ',' ')),7,2) ),''),MAX( SUBSTR(trim(replace(replace(replace(replace(seq,MIN(SUBSTR(seq,1,2),SUBSTR(seq,4,2),SUBSTR(seq,7,2),SUBSTR(seq,10,2),SUBSTR(seq,13,2)),''),'  ',' '),MAX(SUBSTR(seq,1,2),SUBSTR(seq,4,2),SUBSTR(seq,7,2),SUBSTR(seq,10,2),SUBSTR(seq,13,2)),''),'  ',' ')),1,2), SUBSTR(trim(replace(replace(replace(replace(seq,MIN(SUBSTR(seq,1,2),SUBSTR(seq,4,2),SUBSTR(seq,7,2),SUBSTR(seq,10,2),SUBSTR(seq,13,2)),''),'  ',' '),MAX(SUBSTR(seq,1,2),SUBSTR(seq,4,2),SUBSTR(seq,7,2),SUBSTR(seq,10,2),SUBSTR(seq,13,2)),''),'  ',' ')),4,2), SUBSTR(trim(replace(replace(replace(replace(seq,MIN(SUBSTR(seq,1,2),SUBSTR(seq,4,2),SUBSTR(seq,7,2),SUBSTR(seq,10,2),SUBSTR(seq,13,2)),''),'  ',' '),MAX(SUBSTR(seq,1,2),SUBSTR(seq,4,2),SUBSTR(seq,7,2),SUBSTR(seq,10,2),SUBSTR(seq,13,2)),''),'  ',' ')),7,2) ),'')) AS thi,
          MAX( SUBSTR(trim(replace(replace(replace(replace(seq,MIN(SUBSTR(seq,1,2),SUBSTR(seq,4,2),SUBSTR(seq,7,2),SUBSTR(seq,10,2),SUBSTR(seq,13,2)),''),'  ',' '),MAX(SUBSTR(seq,1,2),SUBSTR(seq,4,2),SUBSTR(seq,7,2),SUBSTR(seq,10,2),SUBSTR(seq,13,2)),''),'  ',' ')),1,2), SUBSTR(trim(replace(replace(replace(replace(seq,MIN(SUBSTR(seq,1,2),SUBSTR(seq,4,2),SUBSTR(seq,7,2),SUBSTR(seq,10,2),SUBSTR(seq,13,2)),''),'  ',' '),MAX(SUBSTR(seq,1,2),SUBSTR(seq,4,2),SUBSTR(seq,7,2),SUBSTR(seq,10,2),SUBSTR(seq,13,2)),''),'  ',' ')),4,2), SUBSTR(trim(replace(replace(replace(replace(seq,MIN(SUBSTR(seq,1,2),SUBSTR(seq,4,2),SUBSTR(seq,7,2),SUBSTR(seq,10,2),SUBSTR(seq,13,2)),''),'  ',' '),MAX(SUBSTR(seq,1,2),SUBSTR(seq,4,2),SUBSTR(seq,7,2),SUBSTR(seq,10,2),SUBSTR(seq,13,2)),''),'  ',' ')),7,2) ) AS fou,
          MAX(SUBSTR(seq,1,2),SUBSTR(seq,4,2),SUBSTR(seq,7,2),SUBSTR(seq,10,2),SUBSTR(seq,13,2)) AS fif
   FROM source_table
)
WHERE (seq<>'00 00 00 00 00' AND Date BETWEEN '1939-01-07' AND '2012-12-24')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Column aliases define names for the *output* of the SELECT.

To use them in the SELECT clause itself, you have to add another layer of indirection:

```
SELECT c1 FROM (SELECT 42 AS c1)
```

Comment: ...so long, and thanks for all the fish! So, if i want to use the query above i need to give up on aliases to shorten the length of the query itself (or, yes, use nested subqueries for each level of data gathering: i already did that and it actually worked, but readability goes to hell... well, faster). Any chances to shorten the length of the update question's query? And Thanks for your answer, of course.

Comment: Aaargh! *Do* use subqueries, and if those get too long, use views, or write a helper tool to write them.

Comment: ok, ok. Just asking. I 'create' the view, and now all works happily, opening an universe of possibilities elsewhere. Which is good. Thank you for your help.